# Creating a Dataframe of Proportions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list of lists like such:

`[[person_a,code_1],[person_a,code_2],[person_a,code_3],[person_b,code_1],[person_b,code_1],[person_b,code_1],[person_a,code_4],[person_b,code_2]...]`

I would like the achieve the following:

```
          code_1  code_2 code_3 code_4
person a   .2500   .2500   .2500    .2500
person b   .6667   .3333   0.0    0.0
```

I've used `prop.table` in R to achieve this before but am wondering if there is a Python equivalent. I can convert my list of list to a dataframe, what I'm interested in is some function that can generate each persons code proportions.

Comment: Do you mean a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I do mean a pandas dataframe. I could convert my list of list to a dataframe but what I really want to know is how to generate each individual persons code proportion

Comment: This looks like python code. Did you really want the R tag? Are R solutions acceptable?

Comment: @G5W: There's no code in the question.

Comment: ChuckF: What is converting it to a dataframe with Pandas doing that's not what you want? What code are you using?

Comment: I left the R tag in as Ive done this using R's prop.table function and was hoping someone familiar with R would know the python equivalent

Comment: @Martineau: what its not doing is generating the code portions. ie person B had 2 instances of code_1 out of the 3 codes he issued. and python 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['person_a', 'code_1'],
    ['person_a', 'code_2'],
    ['person_a', 'code_3'],
    ['person_b', 'code_1'],
    ['person_b', 'code_1'],
    ['person_b', 'code_1'],
    ['person_a', 'code_4'],
    ['person_b', 'code_2']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['person', 'code'])

df = df.assign(relative_frequency=1).groupby(['person', 'code']).count().unstack()
# >>> df
#          relative_frequency                     
# code                 code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
# person                                          
# person_a                  1      1      1      1
# person_b                  3      1    NaN    NaN

>>> df.div(df.sum(1), axis=0)
         relative_frequency                     
code                 code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
person                                          
person_a               0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
person_b               0.75   0.25    NaN    NaN
```